# automatically create folders and hyperlinks

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out a way to automatically do

1. create a folder, with the name used = excel cell value in Column A.
2. automatically create a hyperlink to this folder.

The process on my excel worksheet is as follows

1. Enter Title in Column C (example: C1 value is NAME)
2. Then cell A1 is auto-populated based on CONCATENATE of A1 and B1 (fixed content column) (example NAME_1)

At this point in time, I would like to achieve goals 1 & 2 above without having to run a macro every time, with the following deliverables:

1. a new folder located on the same directory as where my workbook is located.
2. a hyperlink is generated in Column G (in our example, it would be in G1).

So far I have gotten to the point of

1. I can run a macro (either on a cell in Column A, or range within Column A) and this will generate the folders (and subfolders) indeed at the right location. This works :-)
2. then, based on the fact that the name of my folder = cell value in the same row/column A - I just type =A(x) (in our example A1) and I have a macro that automatically converts this to a hyperlink to the right location   (combination of didcellchange -->convert to hyperlink). This also works.

I cannot take it to the next level  - what I really want to do is as soon as I enter a Title in Column C, automatically, the workbook detects the change/data entry to Column C and

1. creates a folder based on the concatenate entry of COLUMN A
2. creates a hyperlink to the folder.

OPTIONAL Nice-to-have(s) would be

1. the macro actually giving an option to navigate to where the folders should be installed.
2. hyperlink auto-updating correctly to the correct location (now pointing always to where the current workbook is located - Activeworkbook.path) / or if a link replies with Cannot find folder in specified location, a Browser window opens to update to the correct folder location

I have a suspicion that this might be too complicated to achieve.
If anybody can help with this, I would be extremely grateful - or if you indeed think that I am far too ambitious with this, let me know.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Open the VBA editor
2. Double click on Sheet(Sheet1) in the VBAProject Window (all the way to the left)
   -or- choose Sheet(WhateverYourSheetNameIsJustSelectIt)
3. Paste all of the following code in

   ```
   Public blnFolderFound As Boolean
   Option Explicit

   Private Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
   Function gUsername() As String
   Dim lngLen As Long
   Dim strBuffer As String
   Const dhcMaxUserName = 255
   strBuffer = Space(dhcMaxUserName)
   lngLen = dhcMaxUserName
      If CBool(GetUserName(strBuffer, lngLen)) Then gUsername = Left$(strBuffer, lngLen - 1)
   End Function


   Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim endRow As Long
   Dim rng As Range, c As Range
   Dim currPath As String

   endRow = Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row ''Find end row in column C

   Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(endRow, 3)) ''check each used cell in column C
    For Each c In rng '' For each cell in range
      If c.Value <> vbNullString And c.Hyperlinks.Count = 0 Then  ''test to see if cell not empty and no hyperlink to speed loop up
    Cells(c.Row, 1).Value = Cells(c.Row, 3).Value & "_" & Cells(c.Row, 2).Value ''concatenate the two values

    ''Test to see if file exists and create on if it doesn't
     currPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
     If currPath = vbNullString Then currPath = "C:\Users\" & gUsername & "\Desktop" ''save folder to desktop if file isn't saved
       folderExists currPath, Cells(c.Row, 1).Value

      ''if the folder is found, move on to the next cell to check
      If blnFolderFound = True Then GoTo nextCellToCheck

      ''if the folder wasn't found and one was created in the folderExists function, add a hyperlink
       ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:=currPath & "\" & Cells(c.Row, 1).Value, TextToDisplay:=c.Value


       Else: End If
       nextCellToCheck:
       blnFolderFound = False
   Next c

   Set rng = Nothing


   End Sub

   Function folderExists(s_directory As String, s_folderName As String)
   Dim obj_fso As Object, obj_dir As Object, obj_folder As Object

   Set obj_fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") '' create a filesystem object
   Set obj_dir = obj_fso.GetFolder(s_directory) ''create a folder object


   For Each obj_folder In obj_dir.SubFolders '' for each folder in the active workbook's folder
      If obj_fso.folderExists(s_directory & "\" & s_folderName) = True Then blnFolderFound = True: Exit For    ''see if the file exists
   Next

   If blnFolderFound = False Then obj_fso.CreateFolder (s_directory & "\" & s_folderName) ''if it doesn't exist create one

   Set obj_fso = Nothing
   Set obj_dir = Nothing

   End Function
   ```

I added a condition to save to the user's desktop if the file has not been saved. Enter the value to concatenate in column b and then enter the other value in column c. You might have to modify this a little to fit your needs but it should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks UberNublsTrue. Would this also work on Mac without recompiling?